# Previous Button Returns to First for Some Reason in Rails 3 Using Nested Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a next button that is working great, but previous button just does not want to play nice. Funny thing is that I've tried to build this a few different ways referencing methods on SO and elsewhere, but previous always goes to the earliest record...

In my submission model:

```
   def previous
     self.class.first(:conditions => ["created_at < ?", created_at], :order => "created_at asc")
   end

   def next
     self.class.first(:conditions => ["created_at > ?", created_at], :order => "created_at asc")
   end
```

And in my view:

```
<% if @submission.previous %>
  <%= link_to "previous", contest_submission_path(@contest, @submission.previous),
                        :class => 'pull-left btn btn-large' %>
<% end %>
<% if @submission.next %>
  <%= link_to "next", contest_submission_path(@contest, @submission.next),
                        :class => 'pull-right btn btn-large' %>
<% end %>
```

Like I said, next works great, but previous returns to the earliest record. I'm nearing wits end with this one. Anybody have an answer?

EDITED

Logs:

```
Started GET "/contests/1/submissions/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-30 08:08:52 -0800
Processing by SubmissionsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"contest_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY users.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
  Contest Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "contests".* FROM "contests" WHERE "contests"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Submission Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."id" = $1 ORDER BY submissions.created_at ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."id" = $1 ORDER BY submissions.created_at ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = 1 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = 'Submission' ORDER BY comments.created_at DESC, created_at
   Submission Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE (created_at < '2012-10-08 14:32:40.590930') ORDER BY submissions.created_at ASC, created_at asc LIMIT 1
   Submission Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE (created_at > '2012-10-08 14:32:40.590930') ORDER BY submissions.created_at ASC, created_at asc LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE (created_at > '2012-10-08 14:32:40.590930') ORDER BY submissions.created_at ASC, created_at asc LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY users.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
  Image Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."parent_id" = 2 AND "images"."parent_type" = 'User' LIMIT 1
  Rendered submissions/_follow_unfollow.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Image Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."parent_id" = 1 AND "images"."parent_type" = 'Submission' LIMIT 1
  Rendered submissions/_hide_comments_form.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered comments/_comment.html.erb (3.5ms)
  Rendered submissions/show.html.erb within layouts/application (21.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (4.3ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."parent_id" = 2 AND "images"."parent_type" = 'User' LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "assignments" ON "roles"."id" = "assignments"."role_id" WHERE "assignments"."user_id" = 2
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (4.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.7ms)
```

Completed 200 OK in 105ms (Views: 97.8ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)

Log #2

```
Started GET "/contests/1/submissions/%23%3CActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fc3b5e50af8%3E" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-30 08:43:15 -0800
Processing by SubmissionsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"contest_id"=>"1", "id"=>"#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fc3b5e50af8>"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY users.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
  Contest Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "contests".* FROM "contests" WHERE "contests"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Submission Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fc3b5e50af8>"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Submission with id=#   <ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fc3b5e50af8>):
app/controllers/submissions_controller.rb:89:in `find_submission'
```

Final Solution:

In submission.rb

```
   default_scope order: 'submissions.created_at DESC'

   def previous_sub
     self.class.where("created_at > ?", created_at).reorder("created_at asc").first 
   end

   def next_sub
     self.class.where("created_at < ?", created_at).reorder("created_at desc").first 
   end
```

In view (show):

```
<% if @submission.previous_sub %>
  <%= link_to "previous", contest_submission_path(@contest, @submission.previous_sub),
                        :class => 'pull-left btn btn-large' %>
<% end %>
<% if @submission.next_sub %>
  <%= link_to "next", contest_submission_path(@contest, @submission.next_sub),
                        :class => 'pull-right btn btn-large' %>
<% end %>
```

I ended up exchanging the names of the methods, so that the show record order would match the index, which is scoped in DESC order or most recent to earliest.

Comment: Why did you use different orders (asc and desc)?

Comment: Your query for previous works well for me. Are you sure you have your correct instance variables? Did you try it at console?

Comment: @AlperKarapınar thanks for verifying independently. In the console it does the same thing, previous returns to record one. Based on your feedback, I tried changing the names of the methods to next_sub and previous_sub and tested that in the browser and in the console with the same result. Previous still returns to the first record. If anyone has any other suggestions, lmk

Comment: Strange. I only copy and pasted your previous method in any of my models, and called `MyClass.last.previous` in console, result is always as expected. I tested this because i'd use, `class.where("created_at < ?", created_at).order("created_at desc").limit(1)` syntax. but they produce exactly same sql.

Comment: @AlperKarapınar It works for me with two records, but when I add a third and try "previous" to go from from 3 to 2, it skips from 3 to 1. Just curious, are you testing 2 records or 3?

Comment: `object = MyClass.find(1500)` and `object.previous` is returning object with id 1499. Can you show us the sql query that your method is generating? Is it looking ok?

Comment: @AlperKarapınar I edited the log file onto the end of the question. See anything?

Comment: The query is not OK, it shows `ORDER BY` **submissions.created_at ASC, created_at asc** Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, but your log shows

```
SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" 
WHERE (created_at < '2012-10-08 14:32:40.590930') 
ORDER BY submissions.created_at ASC, created_at asc LIMIT 1
```

If this is a query that searches for previous, this is where it fails (because it orders the previous dates in ascending order, and takes the first - the earliest). Could it be you forgot to restart the app after making changes (though it should be reloaded automatically in dev mode)?

Or it is possible you have `default_scope` or some other scope that breaks the conditions. I wonder why there is `submissions.created_at ASC, created_at asc` - twice? Probably `submissions.created_at ASC` is a default scope.

I'd suggest you to use new AR query syntax, and perhaps `reorder` to exclude other ordering scopes:

```
self.class.where("created_at < ?", created_at).reorder("created_at desc").first
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and for pointing out where things are going wrong. I added a second log file to the answer. Getting an error on the submission id when I replace the syntax.

Comment: I fixed my suggested code. it was not selecting the first record, just returned the relation

Comment: This is working now. I had to change next to asc to make it work and will post the final solution at the end of the question so it's clear to others. Thanks everyone!